# Count specific enum values with JPA rather than manually

Tags: java, jpa, optimization, kotlin

I have a list of status enum values which I am currently iterating over and using a basic counter to store how many in my list have the specific value that I am looking for. I want to improve greatly on this however and think that there may be a way to use some kind of JPA query on a paging and sorting repository to accomplish the same thing.

My current version which isn't as optimized as I would like is as follows.

```
public enum MailStatus {
   SENT("SENT"),
   DELETED("DELETED"),
   SENDING("SENDING"),
}

val mails = mailService.getAllMailForUser(userId).toMutableList()
mails.forEach { mail ->
                if (mail.status === MailStatus.SENT) {
                    mailCounter++
                }
            }
```

With a paging and sorting JPA repository is there some way to query this instead and get a count of all mail that has a status of sent only?

I tried the following but seem to be getting everything rather than just the 'SENT' status.

```
fun countByUserIdAndMailStatusIn(userId: UUID, mailStatus: List<MailStatus>): Long
```

Comment: You're using Java enums with JPA. This should work only with Converters. Check them first.

Comment: You can surely get what you want.... you can even get a `Map<MailStatus, Long>` returning what `SELECT mailStatus, COUNT(*) GROUP BY mailStatus` would do. Unfortunately, I can't tell you how (I'm using a different tool), but somebody will.